# How to generate ListBox items dynamicaly based on type of value (bool/string/int)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a project where:
AS IS: I am generating ListBox based on DataTemplate, with data from ObservableCollection (using binding on property) - this works fine. It contains just texdtBlock with Name and TextBox with value (two way binding).

TO BE: I want to generate dynamicaly types of fields for values depending on type of value. Value can be string - TextBox, int - TextBox (ideal would be to check whether user uses only numbers), double, and bool - CheckBox.

Here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLocked}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Here C# code behind:

```
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    ListBox1.ItemsSource = valuesList;
```

While valuesList contains objects which have:
string name;
string value; (must be parsed)
string type; (later enum)

Could you give me, please, some hints on how to generate this kind of XAML? I mean is it possible to do it using binding, or should I create "ListBoxRow" or something in the code behind and fill the listbox with that? I would like a cleaner solution. That way, I think I wouldn't use binding and might need tons of code to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to bind your listbox and have each row have custom controls depending on the type currently in the 'valuesList'?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As
Name John
Age 45
HasCar checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to this, but this should be the easiest way - if it fullfills your needs.

**DataTemplateSelector**

A `DataTemplateSelector` decides what `DataTemplates` to use dependend on your overwritten logic.

```
public class MySampleClass
{
    public string Name;

    public object Value;
}


public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

    public DataTemplate BooleanTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate DoubleTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate StringTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        MySampleClass temp = item as MySampleClass;


        if(temp.Value is bool)
        {
            return BooleanTemplate;
        }
        else if(temp.Value is double)
        {
            return DoubleTemplate;
        }
        else if(temp.Value is string)
        {
            return StringTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

        }

        // And so on

    }
}
```

And this is - how to use it

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLocked}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLocked}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<selector:MyTemplateSelector BooleanTemplate="{StaticResource BooleanTemplate}"
                             StringTemplate="{StaticResource StringTemplate}"
                             x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"
                             />

<ListBox ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" />
```

And this is without using `Resources`

```
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                        <selector:MyTemplateSelector>
                            <selector:MyTemplateSelector.StringTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLocked}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </selector:MyTemplateSelector.StringTemplate>
                            <selector:MyTemplateSelector.BooleanTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLocked}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </selector:MyTemplateSelector.BooleanTemplate>
                        </selector:MyTemplateSelector>

                    </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                </ListBox>
```

Please think about that `selector` is a definied namespace that depends on the project in your solution. For example `xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:MyApp.MyFolder.Selector"`!!!

Comment: thank you, this looks good to me. I am trying to use your sample in my code and I am getting few errors. I forgot to mention, I am using WPF. Is this in WPF? Because 1. I don't know where to put those datatemplates  - visualstudio doesn't like it anywhere, and also it doesn't know selector.
It seems that listbox accepts only one datatemplate. And x:Key is not allowed for the datatemplate, only x:Name...
Maybe I look stupid now for something I do not see, but a further advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This `XAML` mate. I will change the sample to make it handle easier.